# Query InfluxDB with a Flux string throws Syntax Error

Tags: influxdb

I inserted the below into my influxdb *bucket* named **test**.

```
t0921 name="A",population=93215,date_mod="2004-5-29"
t0922 name="B",population=23719,date_mod="2004-7-6"
t0923 name="C",population=43817,date_mod="2004-8-12"
```

Ran the following command... just as [the documentation says](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/cli/influx/query/#query-influxdb-with-a-flux-string)

```
influx query 'from(bucket:"test")|> range(start:-24h)'
```

...Got the error

```
Syntax Error
```

Have been trying for hours but still cannot figure out. Could anyone help me what I am doing wrong?
I am new to this *Flux* language and been reading [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/flux/language/) but maybe I am missing something.

Comment: Works well for me, do you only have "Syntax Error" ? Or are there more details ?